# Почему цикл while будет бесконечным?

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
var x = false;
var c = false;
setTimeout(function() {x = true; alert('from timeset ' + x);}, 1000);
while(!c) { c = x; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В JS нет **многопоточности**, и цикл не передаст управление следующему ивенту пока не выполнится. Более подробнее про `eventloop` можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Answer (score 1):

`JS` работает всегда в одном потоке, если позволяет функциональность, асинхронно. Поочередно из очереди событий берутся задачи и выполняются, в данном случае произойдет так, что задача `while` т.е цикл, будет выполнятся бесконечно, и `JS` не когда не дойдет до следующего элемента в очереди, а именно нашей `callback` функции, где меняются значение переменных.

Comment: Букв много, пользо мало... event loop - не fifo(даже последовательные вызовы setImmediate не гарантируют порядка), да и не весь код в него попадает. "Вызовы функций, суммы и другие детали" синхронны и ни в какую очередь не попадают. setTimeout - синхронная функция. Вот callback будет вызван асинхронно.

Comment: @vp_arth не очень понял, ну как же, в `JS` все события попадают в очередь, откуда потом последовательно выполняются, разве не так?

Comment: События(если речь о DOM Events) не являются частью JS. В event loop они не попадают(они, строго говоря могут быть реализованы по разному), туда попадают их обработчики/коллбеки. И выполняются они не последовательно, а когда те события "происходят". Т.е. вот синхронный код отработал, движок js мониторит циклом все имеющиеся обработчики - не пора ли их вызвать. Если пора - вызывает.

Comment: @vp_arth прислушаюсь к вашим замечаниям. Исправил ответ. Благодарю.